# SQLite3 real data greter than 9999.99 is auto rounded in 1 decimal places

Tags: sqlite

Below is my sample code:

```
Create table T1(amount real)
insert into T1 Values(9999.99)
```

Result is: 9999.99

But for the below insert:

```
insert into T1 Values(10000.19)
```

Result is 10000.2

I tried to change the datatype to string and on the fly convert and sum the amount but still, i got the same result. Is this a limitation in SQLite? Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Are you doing this in the shell? What is SQLite's version? I can't reproduce this result.

Comment: How are you trying to display the returned value?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - SQLite version is 1.0.79.0

Comment: @CL. - upon inserting the amount, the decimal change when i select the table.

Comment: How (with what software) are you trying to select and display the returned value?

Comment: @CL. - I am creating windows app using vs2010. Using the app I am loading csv files into sqlite and display data using the reportviewer.

Comment: That is a problem with how the reportviewer formats numbers.

Comment: @CL. - But my issue is in the sqlite table not in the reportviewer. Sorry to confuse you, the result i mentioned above is when i select the table.

Comment: SQLite never changes values; your problem is with how the value is displayed.

Comment: @CL. - I think I get it now, I was slow to pickup when you ask me about the software I am using to display the value. I forgot that it must be the browser I used when viewing sqlite object. Thank you for enlightening me on this.